# Word for someone who's ready to go at a moment's notice

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to represent someone who is ready to pack everything up and move out rapidly at a moment's notice. The context is that this will go on an award, as in "[The team name]'s [word] award"

Comment: Well, there is "rapid response", but that is usually for medical teams, and sometimes military forces.

Comment: How about "fireman"?

Comment: 'Rolling stone' would be an individual fitting that description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single word?  From TheFreeDictionary -

"[The team's name] **[preparedness](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/preparedness)** award"

> The state of being prepared

Prepared: made ready, suitable or fit before hand!

Comment: Thank you :) though not a single word I think "rapid preparation" fits my intention best